# How to filter by status in a Plugin?

Tags: database, plugin

In a plugin, I have this as part of the SQL's WHERE clause:

```
$where_sql = "`store_table`.`channel_id` = {$this->channel_ids->stores}
                AND `regions`.{$this->field_column_names->region->region_name} IN ({$regions})
                AND `regions`.{$this->field_column_names->region->region_name} != ''
                AND `address_types`.{$this->field_column_names->address_type->address_type} = 'Physical'
                AND `store_address_data_grid_table`.{$this->grid_column_names->store_address_data->store_address_latitude} != ''
                AND `store_address_data_grid_table`.{$this->grid_column_names->store_address_data->store_address_longitude} != ''
        ";
```

I need this query to respect that entry's status (e.g. status = Open). How do I add that to this query?

**EDIT 1:**

It looks like the `status` value is saved in `exp_channel_titles` and actually stores the value values ("open", "closed") instead of an id. Anyway, I'm not sure how I'd add this to the WHERE clause.

Comment: Can you post the full query, this appears to just be the where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to perform a JOIN on the entry id column in the two tables then set a WHERE clause for titles table. If you're unfamiliar with JOINs then if you can post the full query we may be able to work it out for you.

Comment: I can do a JOIN. I'm just not sure which table to be JOINing. Where do I get the status of a channel entry?

Comment: The entry status is in the exp_channel_titles table.